# How do you select values from two different tables with a join/union?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables

**User**

```
ID   Name  
1    test      
2    test2
```

and

**Application**

```
UserID    URL
  1       website1
  2       website2
```

I am trying to perform a query that will create something similar to this.

**QUERY RESULTS**

```
Name     URL
test     website1
test2    website2
```

**My Attempt**

```
SELECT u.Name, a.URL FROM users as u, application as a INNER JOIN u.ID = a.UserID
```

I tried this but it doesn't seem to be working.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Approach is good, but syntax is wrong. Check MySQL documentation for JOIN syntax. Easy.

Comment: Is the table name Application or artist_application?  Conflicting information.

Comment: Why are you trying this with Join? We can get this with simple query... SELECT u.Name, a.URL FROM users as u, artist_application as a where u.ID = a.UserID

Comment: I didn't realize you could do it without using join. Thanks for the info Gowri.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few items to note, table aliases do not need `as` and `join` infers an inner join.  Also this query depends on the actual name of the application table, you may need to replace with `artist_application`.

```
SELECT u.Name, a.URL 
FROM users u 
join application a
on u.ID = a.UserID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `JOIN`

```
Select
u.Name, 
a.URL
from 
`USERS` u
INNER JOIN artist_application a on (u.id = a.userId)
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax would be

```
SELECT u.Name, a.URL 
FROM users as u
left join artist_application as a on u.ID = a.UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.Name, a.URL 
FROM users as u, artist_application as a 
WHERE u.ID = a.UserID
```

Comment: Can you please add some text so that it makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
SELECT u.Name, a.URL
FROM users as u, artist_application as a
WHERE u.ID = a.UserID
```

Comment: But the Questioner asked the answer with JOIN/UNION

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

SELECT u.Name, a.URL FROM users as u INNER JOIN artist_application as a on u.ID = a.UserID